# Mouse click issue

Tags: windows-10, mouse

Hi I have a huge Problem with my Mouse. Problem:
My mouse clicks don't get register. It's not that it dont work at all. It most of the time working at a certain area but on others it does nothing. For example I can use my browser without any problem but cant click on anything on the desktop or Taskbar. 
Sometimes it also switches left with right mouse button or just registers random clicks.

Solutions I tried:

- obviously restart pc
- tried a different mouse
- reinstalled mouse drivers
- started pc in save mode

The only thing that helps temporarely (about 10sec) is if I do “Ctr + Alt + Del” and then exit again with “Esc”

Now the really weird thing. I had exactly the same problem two days ago on the pc of my father. So I worked on the pc of my father, now I am working on my own pc again, and suddently have the same problem. The only thing that combines them is the hardware I plugget in like 2 Monitors - 1 Webcam - Mouse - and a wacom tablet

although I've used the wacom for years on my pc I deinstalled the software and unplug it without any difference.

Software I recently installed on both systems: Adobe InDesign, OBS, Zoom

I run out of Ideas pls help!

operation system: Win10

Answer (score 0):

I've used CTL-ALT-DEL for a problem when I RDP - sometime the Shift/CTL/Alt states get out of sync between the client and server - pressing ctl-alt-del seems to fix this 
I think if I press and release every shift key (Leftshift, rightshift , left-ctrl,right-ctrl, left-alt, right-alt ) will also fix it - but CTL-ALT-DEL is faster

I've also had the problem with mouse clicks for the same reason - that is the computer acts as if I am holding down one of the shift keys when I click, so the computer sees the click - but because I have CTL down it does not act as a left mouseclick

My point is it could be a faulty keyboard or missed key-up - My hope is that this helps you find the actual problem